# Using RequireJS's optimizer with a single build file to produce multiple outputs

Tags: build, requirejs

I'm currently working on a big JavaScript project and I am using RequireJS to impose some structure.

I'd like to configure a build using the optimizer ([r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs)) so my project will be bundled in one minified file (for production purposes). This is fairly easy, however I have a couple of packages in my project and would like to have each package built to its own minified javascript file.

Example of the folder structure:

```
src/core/main.js
src/core/util/HashMap.js (
src/package1/main.js
src/package1/views/view1.js
```

Where the `main.js` files are the entry points for the modules.

I would like to configure my build in such a way that after the build is completed, I would have the following two outputs:

```
core.min.js
package1.min.js
```

However I can't seem to get this to work. Using the `modules` property of the build config doesn't seem to minify each module.

Can anyone shed a light on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you have a build per module, with a build profile per module that uses the `empty:` scheme to eliminate non-module code from that particular module's output? http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty

Comment: That would be a possibility, however I prefer having a single configuration file, requiring me to run the build command only once

Comment: Can you use `exclude` for each module? https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/c319938abb55f493d0a46566114364c4935321de/build/example.build.js#L240

Comment: I don't see how using exclude would result in a single minified JS file for  each module?

Comment: Exclude wouldn't, but it would prevent non-module code that is required by the module, from being included in the module's optimised output.

Comment: Agreed, but do you know by any chance what configuration I need to set up to have each module minified to one JS file? Thanks for your time so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember exactly what was wrong at the time I asked this (could even have been a bug of the current RequireJS version I was using at the time), but this kind of setup is easily achievable by using (as I've stated in my question) the `modules` section. Simply declare your modules as follows:

```
optimize:"uglify",
dir: 'out',
modules: [
    {
        name: "src/core/Main"
    },
    {
        name: "src/package1/Main"
    }
],
...
```

This will result in the following structure under `out`:

```
out
|--core
:  |--Main.js
|--package1
:  |--Main.js
```

There are options available to rename the output files, to flatten the output folder, to exclude all `core` packages from `package1` and many more, but basically this was the structure I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting Require.JS to do everything precisely the way I needed all by itself.

I am currently using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for this. I have the [Require.JS plugin for Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) configured to combine a dozen module files into just 2 files. I do use `modules`, `empty:` and `exclude` here and there to help achieve this. Require.JS is still the best way to combine modules based on their dependencies.

Then I use the [Uglify plugin for Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) to separately minify the output.

While this might not help with your use-case, I'm also using [Grunt's concat plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) to help get my output just the way I like it.

This is all in a `Gruntfile.js` and so all of this happens automatically with `grunt watch` whenever a file changes, making the develop-refresh-test loop just that bit nicer.